# Facebook review approval with an Intel XDK android app fails due to missing login

Tags: android, facebook, intel-xdk

I'm trying to get my android application approved by facebook, but I keep getting the same inexplicable error back:

> **General**
>
> One or more of your App Center Listed Platforms doesn't use
>   Facebook Login. Please integrate Facebook Login, and clarify how to
>   login with Facebook in your Review Instructions. Otherwise, remove the
>   platform(s) from your "App Details" tab.

Now, my app has a big blue facebook-login button on its main screen, so don't think that a missing facebook login is the problem, I think a screenshot of my facebook app settings screen holds a much more plausible explanation:
[image]

In order to add facebook support to an Intel XDK facebook app you've previously had to add a website going to html5tools-software.intel.com and use that same address as an **App Domain** for the application. I think the missing Facebook-login error comes from that website being tested together with my android app (which it shouldn't, it has nothing to do with my app).

What I would like to know is how to get a wrapped HTML5 application for android approved or if there are any other ways for Intel XDK apps to be approved as facebook apps (different App Domain perhaps?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to ignore the app domains (I was setting it to 'html5tools-software.intel.com' in accordance to intels tutorial on how to do it) and **NOT** add a second 'facebook app' as the tutorial says (it wants you to add a web page with url html5tools-software.intel.com). Skip those two and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect

https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#login

Says that native apps must use the SDK, which is provided by the plugin.

Comment: I am using another implementation which is not technically using the Facebook SDK, I'll try to replace the implementation and see if it works.

Comment: Well, the http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect plugin seems to be the one I was using originally (although fetched from here: https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin). So that doesn't solve the problem...